# How to send to a "group contact" or distribution list using Google Inbox

Tags: gmail, inbox

After moving over to Inbox I am unable to send emails to groups/distribution lists I have set up in my Gmail contacts.

I must be missing something simple..  Can someone set me straight?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this one](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/70085/send-email-to-google-contact-group-with-inbox) on [webapps.se].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Gmail google group: "Not currently a feature of Google Inbox"

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/gmail/inbox$20group$20email/gmail/U-L6Qsj68gw/oEv7uxiBvuEJ

Comment: Even at this date, there are only workarounds. They are all cumbersome. One thing I have to do often is forward an email sent directly to me to the group which represents the board I chair. The workarounds don't work for forward. It is maddening that in Inbox I have to enter each person's email separately to forward, so I usually go back to old Gmail to forward it.